# Problem adding content inside an inline-block container

Tags: html, css

Here is my current code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #000;
    color: #666;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#panels {
    height: 100%;
}

#left, #right {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #006161;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
#lt {
  height: 50px;
  background: #202020;
}
```

```html
<div id="panels"><div id="left"><div id="lt"></div></div><div id="right"></div></div>
```

The problem appears when I try to add content to the "lt" container, like so:

```html
<div id="lt">1</div>
```

the whole "left" container gets shifted down inside its parent.

[image]

I'd like to know why it happens and how to fix it, thank you!

Comment: I checked in Firefox and Chrome and both are rendering the left container at the top

Comment: In case you are wondering what is the correct answer as SO has a habit to close questions, add `vertical-align: top;` to your `#left, #right { css }`.

Comment: @Gosi *SO has a habit to close questions* --> maybe because the answer already exist (click on the duplicate and see)